# Calculate Dip and Strike

Tags: iphone, objective-c, accelerometer

How do i calculate Dip and Strike from iphone. They are used to measure rocks.
i have to use compass api how do i get the angle from it.
anyone has idea please give me some idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "compass API" is not so much a *compass* as a *magnetometer*. (In other words, if you put your phone near some strong local magnetic field - say, a CRT monitor - you won't only be measuring the Earth's magnetic field.)

[This sample](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Teslameter/) ought to help you on your way. It demonstrates the use of the [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html).

To determine the orientation of the rockface you need to use the [UIAccelerometer](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html) class. Have your ViewController or whatever implement the [UIAccelerometerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometerDelegate_Protocol/UIAccelerometerDelegate/UIAccelerometerDelegate.html) protocol. The [BubbleLevel](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/BubbleLevel/index.html) sample application will show you how to use the API.

The magnetometer then allows you to turn that phone orientation into an orientation relative to magnetic North.

Comment: I need to calculate the stone rocks, for which i use strike.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But strike is perpendicular to north so how can i get those angle by compass?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of asking the same question. I offer part but not full answer.

1. Strike => (Geology) horizontal surface crossing bedding in question: this can be achieved by reading the heading from the CLLocationDirection.magneticHeading
2. Dip.angle => (Geology) horizontal surface & bedding angle: this can be achieved by either CMMotionManager.CMDeviceMotion.CMAttitude.roll or pitch depending on how the iOS device is held to the bedding being measuered.

**EDIT:**
3. Dip.driection => (Geology) actual NSWE orientation of the tilt: Strike + 90 because they are perpendicular clockwise (I think).

I may have not written my answer correctly but my geologist colleagues confirm my readings which is basically 1, 2 and 3 (eg: 43/11SE)

If someone can improve this answer, I appreciate it.